# Monkeyrunner colors outside the lines on a Galaxy Nexus but not on the emulator

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

If I run the following command on a Galaxy Nexus running Jellybean 4.2, Monkey "spills over" into non-app activities.

```
adb shell monkey -p com.mypackage -v 1000
```

For example, it ends up executing presses in the settings activity, changing phone volume, turning on/off wifi, etc.

However, if I run the same command on the emulator, I never have this problem.

Is this a device vs. emulator problem?  Is it particular to some devices and not others?  Is there a known workaround?

Comment: Did you miss something when copy your command line?

Comment: There seem to be two problems areas: devices with softbuttons, and the status bar.  If only there were a way to make monkey avoid those two areas